# Java SWT browser xulrunner crash Java VM

Tags: java, browser, swt, embedding, xulrunner

I'm embedding in a Swing-based application an SWT Browser based on Xulrunner using a proper path and the setting `SWT.MOZILLA`. Mainly I have a class which extends `JPanel`. This class embed a shell with a Browser widget inside. If I create more than just one instance of the class Java VM crash killing the entire application. If I create the browser with `SWT.NONE` (so basically picking up the System's browser) I can display as many browser I want in my application.
Where's the problem?

BTW it's `nsCycleCollector.c` (part of xulrunner) that make the VM crash.

Comment: So, do you really _have_ to use `SWT.MOZILLA`?

Comment: Well, I want xulrunner not the system browser ... I need the same browser instance for Windows/ OSX / GNU/Linux. I want also a dedicated browser with no cookies or history for security reasons. With SWT.NONE I'll share my informations with the system browser that the user normally use to surf the internet. Not sure if I've explained myself correctly. Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to program a SWT / AWT(Swing) bridge on your own. I'm currently using [DJNative](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) for that and it works perfect. Please give it a try ;)

### Own XULRunner installation for SWT Browser

1. First download a xulrunner runtime from mozilla.
2. extract it anywhere and remember the path during bootstrap of your application
3. set following system property `org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath`
   with the path to your xulrunner installation

with that approach you are able to ship a predefined xulrunner installation with your app.

Comment: Thanks! I've already done that but when I start a second browser the Java VM just crash brutally. It's weird because if I use the "SWT.NONE" option, it goes well without any problems. The only problem is that every machine that runs Windows XP (even SP3) will have an extraordinary beautiful Internet Explorer 8 which is old and not-standard-compliant.

Comment: can you check if a hs_err file was created and post that?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same crash situation here.

If you use xulrunner 10.0.4esr, you get this System.err output before the JVM aborts:

```
###!!! ABORT: Main-thread-only object used off the main thread: file e:/builds/moz2_slave/rel-m-esr10-xr-w32-bld/build/xpcom/base/nsCycleCollector.cpp, line 1278
```

I found out that you would need to destroy the nsIBaseWindow of the nsIWebBrowser instance to clean up stuff:

```
nsIWebBrowser webBrowser = (nsIWebBrowser)b.getWebBrowser();
nsIBaseWindow baseWindow = (nsIBaseWindow)webBrowser.queryInterface(nsIBaseWindow.NS_IBASEWINDOW_IID);
baseWindow.destroy();
```

After doing so, you can create new instances of the SWT Browser with Mozilla / xul in it.

The promlem is, you cannot access the nsInterfaces anymore (as Browser.getWebBrowser() returns null)!

Is there any way to get to that nsIBaseWindow object programatically on xulrunner 10 or 24?

Here's a snippet from the crash log (generated with xulrunner 24 and JDK6 runtime):

```
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [xul.dll+0xaa1b4c]  NS_CycleCollectorSuspect2+0xc
C  [xul.dll+0x6d45d1]  xpc_ActivateDebugMode+0x1a588
C  [xul.dll+0x6d1192]  xpc_ActivateDebugMode+0x17149
C  [xul.dll+0xa74003]  JSD_GetValueForObject+0x2b8625
C  [xul.dll+0xa72ffa]  JSD_GetValueForObject+0x2b761c
C  [xul.dll+0x70fdae]  xpc_ActivateDebugMode+0x55d65
C  [xul.dll+0x711bc6]  xpc_ActivateDebugMode+0x57b7d
C  [swt-xulrunner-win32-4426.dll+0x11d6]  Java_org_eclipse_swt_internal_mozilla_XPCOM__1VtblCall__II+0xe
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.mozilla.XPCOM.VtblCall(II)I+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.mozilla.nsIBaseWindow.Create()I+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.MozillaDelegate.createBaseWindow(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/mozilla/nsIBaseWindow;)I+1
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initWebBrowserWindows()V+184
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+665
j  org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;I)V+81
j  XulTest$1.run()V+47
```